# How to optimize the deployment in websphere 6.1

Tags: deployment, jakarta-ee, websphere

We are using Websphere's wsadmin to deploy our application which is packaged as a .ear file, which takes more than an hour to deploy and start the server. Is there any suggested optimized tool to perform the deployment. which will help us in reduce the deployment timing.

Thanks in Advance!
Jay

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your application and framework used. If every time during deployment you do ejb compile, it would be not too much options, and all time cost.
Consider the following:

- use Rational RAD or RSA with build-in
  optimized WebSphere Server.
- use optimized settings  for
  developement in WebSphere admin console
- enable auto-reload and use exploded
  archive and directly copying files to
  it
- use external class-reloading tools
  like JRebel

Comment: Hi Chro, Thanks for your reply, we are not using any ejb's in our project.. It will be great if you could share any link for optimising the settings in websphere admin console.

Answer (score 0):

Are you stating that it takes 1 hour to deploy a single EAR file?

Where is the EAR file located? How big is the EAR file?

Where is wsadmin running from? (the same machine as the WAS Server or from a remote machine)?

If it is running from a remote machine, does it take long to transfer the EAR file to the actual WAS box?

Also why should the WAS Server be started for deploying your application?

I am assuming you are using a DM set up and the wsadmin is connecting to the DM?

Appreciate if you could clarify before people could assist you.

Manglu

Comment: Hi Manglu, Thanks for pointing out. EAR is located in a remote machine and transferred to the WAS box, Size of the .ear is 53MB.

Comment: 1) 1 hour is not part of transferring the EAR 2) WSADMIN is running in the same machine where WAS is installed 3) We are restarting the server after deployment as we faced few inconsistency issues in just restarting the application after deployment. 4) Yes you are correct we are using DM for set up.

Comment: Hi, In the list of wsadmin tasks can we split the 1 hour into these tasks (time taken for the applicaiton install), synchornizing the DM with the node agents and time taken to start the server.                                                          (2) I am trying to understand which component takes the most time (3) Why is the EAR file 53 MB. Are you shipping a number of libraries along with the EAR. 53 MB sounds way too big for an EAR file.

Comment: Yes, 1 hour split is 10 minutes for server configuration (for the initial time) and 50 minutes for deployment + starting 2 clusters. The ear has more than 25 MB of third party jars within it.

Comment: Try this, remove the 25 MB of third party jars and have them as a shared library and try and see if things are any better. I still believe 25 MB for an EAR is too much (after removing the 25 MB of third party jars).  Also take a simple standard sample app which is small in size and see how long it takes to deploy it to your cluster and measure the time taken to see if the size of the app is the real culprit here.